# How to get the X and Y coordinate of TableCell in the TableView JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a ComboBoxTableCell in my TableView, when someone click the ComboBoxTableCell, I want that another Pane will display below the ComboBoxTableCell with a list of items. I tried to get the coordinate of the ComboBoxTableCell  but no luck. Is there any way to get the coordinate? Or Do you have any better way to do this? Below is the image of Sample UI, I want to be done. Thanks.

[image: This is the sample UI I want to be done.]

Here is my method to initialize the TableView

private void initOrderTable(){

```
    this.orderTable.setEditable(true);
    TableColumn nameCol = new TableColumn("Name");
    nameCol.setMinWidth(100);

    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    nameCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Product, String>,ComboBoxTableCell<Product,String>>() {

        @Override
        public ComboBoxTableCell<Product, String> call(TableColumn<Product, String> param) {

           ComboBoxTableCell ct= new ComboBoxTableCell<>();
           ct.setComboBoxEditable(true);

           return ct;
        }
});


    this.orderTable.getItems().addAll("Sample Row");
    this.orderTable.getColumns().addAll(nameCol);

}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of the cell relative to the `Scene` with

```
Point2D location = ct.localToScene(0, 0);
```

or relative to the Screen with

```
Point2D location = ct.localToScreen(0, 0);
```

Those will give you the coordinates of the top left of the cell. You can do

```
Point2D location = ct.localToScene(0, ct.getHeight());
```

to get the coordinates of the bottom left relative to the `Scene`, etc. Obviously you will need to set a listener on the cell to be invoked when you need to show the pane.