# javafx: How to set "setComboBoxEditable" to true within this setCellFactory method?

Tags: java, javafx

Basically, I have managed to create a `comboBoxTableCell` within my `tableView`. The only problem is that I cannot type in any user input and without this function, the `comboBoxTableCell` is no different from a `Choice` box table cell to me.

Now from looking at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html#setComboBoxEditable-boolean-), if I can set `setComboBoxEditable(true)`for `comboBoxTableCell`, then I think my problem will be sorted. Question is how do I do this in the following line of code?

```
public TableColumn<Trade,String> tableColumnX;

tableColumnX.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
tableColumnX.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(obsList));
```

I have taken a second attempt on this using what I saw on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074736/how-to-get-the-x-and-y-coordinate-of-tablecell-in-the-tableview-javafx),

```
    tableColumnX.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Product, String>,ComboBoxTableCell<Product,String>>() {

    @Override
    public ComboBoxTableCell<Product, String> call(TableColumn<Product, String> param) {

       ComboBoxTableCell ct= new ComboBoxTableCell<>();
       ct.setComboBoxEditable(true);

       return ct;
    }});
```

This time I am getting an error:

```
The method setCellFactory(Callback<TableColumn<Product,String>,TableCell<Product,String>>) in the type TableColumn<Product,String> is not applicable for the arguments (new Callback<TableColumn<Product,String>,ComboBoxTableCell<Product,String>>(){})
```

**If I am not clear on any parts of the question, please let me know. I can add in more details for clarification.**

Comment: Can the person explain why you downvoted the question please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Callback<TableColumn<Product, String>,TableCell<Product,String>>()` instead of `Callback<TableColumn<Product, String>,ComboBoxTableCell<Product,String>>()`

Try this :

```
 tableColumnX.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Product, String>,TableCell<Product,String>>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell<Product, String> call(TableColumn<Product, String> param) {

           ComboBoxTableCell<Product, String> ct= new ComboBoxTableCell<>();
           ct.setComboBoxEditable(true);

           return ct;
        }});
```

**Here is an Example**

```
   import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    /**
     *
     * @author
     */
    public class Javafx_test extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {

            TableColumn<String, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>("Column");
            tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData
                    -> {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue());
                    }
            );
            tableColumn.setCellFactory(tableCol -> {
                ComboBoxTableCell<String, String> ct = new ComboBoxTableCell<>();
                ct.getItems().addAll("1", "2");
                ct.setComboBoxEditable(true);

                return ct;
            });
            TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
            tableView.setEditable(true);
            tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
            tableView.getItems().addAll("4", "5");
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tableView);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 100);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```